# I2C sensor not detected on Raspi3

Tags: sensor, raspberry-pi, ph

I am trying to set up a pH sensor from Atlas Scientific using a Raspi3. I am using this [Tutorial](http://myhydropi.com/connecting-a-ph-sensor-to-a-raspberry-pi) to set it up. I have set the sensor to I2C as the LED is blue. The circuit is shown here. I am now trying to run the `i2cdetect -y 1` command, but when it prints out all the I2C ports are `-` instead of having `63` at its position. I think that I have connected my cables connected since they look the same as in the tutorial.

Any idea as to why the I2C sensor is not detected?

Thanks.
[image: Here]

Comment: Does the raspberry Pi have internal pullups for the I2C? If it does not, I2C requires the addition of pull up resistors.

Comment: @vini_i In the tutorial they didn't use any resistors, so I didn't put any.  Any idea how I would go about doing that?

Comment: You should have pull-up resistors. Put some 4k7 or 10k ohm from SDA to 3.3V. Do same for SCL.

Comment: First check what voltage the lines are idling at. Pi runs at 3.3v so the lines would idle at that level. If they are not, then install 10k resistors from SDA to 3.3v and SCL to 3.3v.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`RX` and `TX` are receiving and transmitting lines for UART communication. I2C lines are labeled `SDA` (Serial DAta) and `SCL` (Serial CLock).

Your sensor seems to be capable of UART and I2C communication, the first one being the default.
Following the instructions on the site you linked, you switched the sensor to I2C mode, and the meaning of the IO pins changes:

```
TX -> SDA
RX -> SCL
```

Your Raspberry Pi has UART as well as I2C on different IO pins.
**But you connected the I2C sensor to the UART Port.**
 The I2C port is at about the same position in the **lower row** of the blue adapter board.

For UART communication, connect

```
Sensor TX <-> RPI RX
Sensor RX <-> RPI TX
```

And for I2C connect

```
Sensor TX (SDA) <-> RPI SDA
Sensor RX (SCL) <-> RPI SCL
```

Comment: Thank you, they didn't show the complete circuit so I assumed that the TX goes to TX etc. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

IIC lines are actively driven low and passively pulled high.  No pullup resistors are apparent, so that may be your problem.